# Normalizing data before feeding to RNN

Tags: neural-network, normalization, recurrent-neural-network

I want to feed the following example data into a RNN:

```
[[[100 22 1]
  [120 30 0]
  [232 11 0]]

 [[110 23 1]
  [230 32 1]
  [500 43 1]]]
```

So there are 3 features, the first two are numerical with different scales and the third is binary. The size is 2x3x3, (2 examples, with sequence length 3, and 3 features.
I would like to normalize these data. I read that you do not have to normalize binary features. But what about the other two?
Lets say i use the following method:

```
(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
```

a) Should i normalize them in each example independently? So that means calculate min and max for each separate example?

b) Or should i normalize based on the whole dataset?

Which one is the correct way?

Comment: Same issue. Did you get a solution to this ?

Comment: I decided to normalize (with minmax) based on each feature individually, so with the above small data, i normalize the vector (100,120,232,110,230,500) independently. So i choose to use data from all samples and for each feature. I think this looks the correct one. Using for example (100,22,1), then (120,30,0) etc etc will make 100 and 120 both 1 after normalization, so rnn will treat them as equal, which they are not. Same goes if i use per sample normalization. I am not 100% sure that normalizing based on all samples is correct though, but it seems the correct way to me.

Comment: On the other hand if you want to use unit norm normalization, it seems that you have to normalize per sample and per timestep, so you normalize these data (100,22,1), so the whole feature vector has norm 1. Correct me if i have any mistakes in my calculations.